# Take object out of JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json, oauth, fetch, tumblr

I'm trying to select a specific object in a JSON query. I have decoded it, and although I have spent a few hours searching for an answer, I am unable to determine one for this specific case. I would like to select the URL from the Blogs response, however I can't get past the array.

```
 $oauth->fetch("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info");                                                                                                                   
 $json = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse());                                                                                                                                               
 $url = $json->response->user->blogs;                                                        
 $url1 = array($url->url);    //This line doesn't give me the URL- I'm getting Array ( [0] => )                                                              
 print_r($url1);
```

The output when I don't have the array part in gives me:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => 12748784 [url] => http://12748784.tumblr.com/ [followers] => 0 [primary] => 1 [title] => Untitled [description] => [admin] => 1 [updated] => 1341883193 [posts] => 1 [drafts] => 0 [messages] => 4 [queue] => 0 [ask] => 1 [ask_anon] => [tweet] => N [facebook] => N [facebook_opengraph_enabled] => N [type] => public ) ) ) ) )
```

Thanks for any help you can give me. I'm exhausted from searching.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Tumblr documentation, `blogs` is an array of objects. Therefore, `array($url->url)` makes no sense. It should be `$url1 = $url[0]->url` in your code, which to me, looks horrible.

I'd do something more like this.

```
$blogs = $json->response->user->blogs;
$urls = array();
foreach ($blogs as $object) {
    $urls[] = $object->url;
}
```

This way you get all the blog urls out of the object array. Does this make sense?